# What does it mean for `(compiled code)` to build up on the js heap in chrome dev tools? Is this a memory leak?

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I've been trying to track down a small memory leak in my ReactJS web app. It increases by 10-30 mb over the course of 10 minutes or so.

I took 3 heap snap shots using the chrome dev tools: 1 after the page loaded and was in a stable state, 1 after I performed the action I suspect of leaking, and a 3rd after performing that action a second time. Now I'm looking at what's building up between snapshots.

I see several things, and am working to fix them, but the #1 culprit for build up on the heap between my snapshots is `(compiled code)`. I'm struggling to understand what this represents, and whether it is a leak or not.

What would cause code to be loaded into memory after the page has fully loaded and is in a stable state? Does this indicate a leak?

Comment: If you don't use `eval` or `new Function` and similar dynamic code, it may mean V8 re-compiles hot parts of the code from interpreted byte code into optimized machine code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> What would cause code to be loaded into memory after the page has fully loaded and is in a stable state?

V8 compiles your JavaScript code dynamically. Currently, its execution pipeline looks like this:

- When you first load the page, V8 only very briefly looks at all the JavaScript sources to find out which functions exist, and where they are defined.
- The first time a function is called, it is compiled to "bytecode", which is a very lightly processed version of the JS source that V8's interpreter can execute.
- When V8 observes that some time is being spent interpreting a given function, it compiles it to unoptimized machine code. This compilation is very quick (because no optimizations are performed), and the resulting code is quite a bit faster than the interpreter, but far from perfect.
- When V8 observes that even more time is being spent in such a function, it eventually schedules an optimized compilation job for it. The optimizing compiler runs in the background, spends far more time on optimization, and produces far better code. Once it is done with a given function, the next call to that function can use the optimized machine code for it.

(This is skipping over a bunch of details, but that's the gist of it. Also, we keep working on V8, so if you find articles from five years ago, they'll describe a similar but different situation; and the team is currently once again experimenting with changing things up a bit, so this description will likely become somewhat outdated in due time. Some further reading is [here](https://v8.dev/blog/sparkplug).)

It is totally normal/expected that very few functions are compiled to machine code during page load, in particular because a lot of the code that runs there only runs once to set up stuff.
Once you start using the page's functionality and some of your JS functions run repeatedly and/or for longer, they'll get compiled to machine code, so you'll see more `(compiled code)` in heap snapshots.

> Does this indicate a leak?

No. It just indicates that the multi-tiered JIT compilation system is doing its job.

(*If* you observe the amount of code growing forever, e.g. every time you repeat a certain action you get X amount of additional compiled code and that growth never stops, then that would sound like a leak. That's not what you've described though.)